# Fully saturated liquid and vapour

Tags: thermodynamics, pumps, heating-systems, vapor-pressure

In terms of fully saturated vapour and liquid for water. Why in a real world heat pump cycle for example may the water not exactly reach these saturation lines as indicated in an ideal cycle?

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, processes don't stop at exactly the right phase point.  Real world processes are based on the heat transfer that actually occurs, so it will be (for example) less than 100% vapor, or be slightly superheated.